# How to handdle lots of heavy image assets in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, memory-management

I am creating a game where the levels are created using images, so for each level I'll have one image. I already have 200 levels which means 200 images. To keep the images references I created a ScriptableObject and then added a reference to this scriptable in the GameManager. I took a snapshot from the memory profiler and just by simply referencing this scriptable all the images go to memory. I thought of using the Resources folder, but it's not recommended by unity and also occupies some space in memory (+-10% of the scriptable try). I saw some articles saying that Streaming Assets might be the solution but then I'll need to create the asset bundles for each image or pack them together which is not good.
Can the addressable assets be a good solution for this?

Comment: What is your build target platform?

Comment: Mobile platforms (iOS and Android)

Answer (score 0):

Unity3d keeps all its Assets in Streaming Assets folder including Addressable Bundle. So in your case it's best to use Addressable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Unity `Addressable` is the best solution when it comes to loading and managing large amount of assets without reference. You can either load `Addressable` assets from local or remote location.

Alternatively you can reference same `ScriptableObject` in separate scene and load that scene additively when required.